# build artifacts download from nexus in vsts release definition

Tags: download, azure-devops, release, nexus

I have the build definition which does Maven build. after the build I upload artifacts to nexus repository  using nexus artifacts upload plugin.

From release definition is there any way to download the artifacts from nexus for my deployment?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using nexus 2.x**, you can use the REST API to download artifacts from nexus repo:

```
wget "http://local:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?g=com.mycompany&a=my-app&v=LATEST" --content-disposition
```

or

```
curl --insecure "https://local:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/content?r=public&g=log4j&a=log4j&v=1.2.17&p=jar&c=" > log4j.ja
```

**If you are using nexus 3.x**, you can use below ways to download artifacts from nexus repo:

- Option 1: Use maven command

  ```
  mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:copy -Dartifact=log4j:log4j:1.2.17:jar -DoutputDirectory=./
  ```
- Option 2: use wget with bash script to download:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  repo="https://nexus.url.com"
  groupId=$1
  artifactId=$2
  version=$3

  # optional
  classifier=$4
  type=$5

  if [[ $type == "" ]]; then
    type="jar"
  fi
  if [[ $classifier != "" ]]; then
    classifier="-${classifier}"
  fi

  groupIdUrl="${groupId//.//}"
  filename="${artifactId}-${version}${classifier}.${type}"

  if [[ ${version} == *"SNAPSHOT"* ]]; then repo_type="snapshots"; else repo_type="releases"; fi

  if [[ $repo_type == "releases" ]]
   then
     wget --no-check-certificate "${repo}/repository/releases/${groupIdUrl}/${artifactId}/${version}/${artifactId}-${version}${classifier}.${type}" -O ${filename} -k
   else
     versionTimestamped=$(wget -q -O- --no-check-certificate "${repo}/repository/snapshots/${groupIdUrl}/${artifactId}/${version}/maven-metadata.xml" | grep -m 1 \<value\> | sed -e 's/<value>\(.*\)<\/value>/\1/' | sed -e 's/ //g')

     wget --no-check-certificate "${repo}/repository/snapshots/${groupIdUrl}/${artifactId}/${version}/${artifactId}-${versionTimestamped}${classifier}.${type}" -O ${filename}
   fi

  ´´´

  usage
   script.sh groupid artifactid version classifier type
   ex:
   script.sh log4j log4j 4.2.18 sources zip 
   script.sh log4j log4j 4.2.19  -> get jar as default
   script.sh log4j log4j 4.2.19-SNAPSHOT  -> get jar as default
  ```

More details, you can refer [Fetching artifact programmatically through REST/API fro Nexus2/3](https://gist.github.com/cedricwalter/e7739aab3d370ef83f1a13b8322e50be#fetching-artifact-programmatically-through-restapi-fro-nexus23).