# Associate build artifact to Nexus repo

Tags: azure-devops, nexus, azure-devops-extensions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash

I created a custom Nexus upload script in PowerShell to upload a build artifact from artifact staging directory to Nexus repo. In the PS script i'm running the following command so the build pipeline is associated with the artifact in Nexus repo. But I'm not sure what to put for artifacttype, according to the documentation, it seems like the options are container|filepath|versioncontrol|gitref|tfvclabel.

```
Write-Host "##vso[artifact.associate artifacttype=filepath;artifactname=$fileName]http://nexusDNS:8081/repository/$Repository"
```

Anyways, after associating the build pipeline to the release pipeline, I ran a release and it will initially try to download the linked artifact and this is the message I get.

Downloading artifact Testartifact.zip from: http:\nexusDNS:8081\repository\Test\Testartifact.zip

because I declared artifacttype as 'filepath' it's converting the http:// to http:.

Could someone help me how I can make release pipeline to download the artifact directly from Nexus? Would I have to write another script to use Nexus API to download the artifact as part of the release task?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Sonatype Nexus Repository Release Artifact](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=soft-cor.nexus-custom-release-artifact-extension&targetId=0933e8b2-f504-4b7e-9e9e-ce303b05ea59) extension. This extension provides support for Nexus Maven Repositories when leveraging Release Pipelines, the initial version includes Release Pipeline Artifact support for Nexus Maven Repositories as well as providing Azure Pipelines tasks for downloading assets from Maven Repositories.

This extension requires you to first configure a service connection to connect to your Nexus Repository server `(project settings -> Services Connections tab and create a New Service Connection of type Sonatype Nexus Repository)`. Once connected, you can link a source artifact from the a Nexus Maven Repository and use these artifacts in your Release Pipeline.

[image]

In addition , you can also use the REST API to download artifacts from nexus repo. For details,please refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123347/build-artifacts-download-from-nexus-in-vsts-release-definition).

```
wget "http://local:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?g=com.mycompany&a=my-app&v=LATEST" --content-disposition
```

Comment: Hello Hugh, is this even correct? Write-Host "##vso[artifact.associate artifacttype=filepath;artifactname=$fileName]http://nexusDNS:8081/repository/$Repository"